# Getting Partial Response with Asynchronous XMLHTTP

Tags: http, vbscript

How can I asynchronously read XMLHTTP before it’s finished in VBS?  The example
below (which has a ”The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available”
error if sleep times are not long enough) uses a big Wikipedia page, but ultimately I
am thinking to use this for an infinite webpage/stream that never finishes loading.  So,
is there a simple way to modify this example to get partial HTTP responses early?

```
strFileURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm"  ' or any big webpage

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")   ' all of these xmlhttp options have no "streaming success"
' Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
' Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
' Set objXMLHTTP = Createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
' Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, true
objXMLHTTP.send()

' Is there something other than ResponseText to avoid error and get partial result below (i.e., read html like a stream)?
WScript.Sleep 500                   ' need to play with this time to try to cause mystate1=3 below
mystate1 = objXMLHTTP.ReadyState    ' should be 3
myscan = objXMLHTTP.ResponseText    ' CAUSES ERROR if mystate1 < 4 (comment this line out to avoid error)
WScript.Sleep 1000
mystate2 = objXMLHTTP.ReadyState    ' should be 4
myscan = objXMLHTTP.ResponseText

MsgBox(mystate1)
MsgBox(mystate2)
MsgBox(myscan)

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, at least not by using an XMLHTTPRequest. As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361), neither `responseText` nor `responseBody` are available before the request is completed.

Comment: OK, so is there a different property I can use?  If I change ResponseText to ResponseStream in my example, I don't get an error until MsgBox which tells me that the property exists but I simply don't know how to view any details about it.  I imagine that I should be able to at least view the size of this growing ResponseStream, but can't even do that.  If you know how I can do that, or any other VBS way to view realtime "loading progress", it would help.  I'm actually more concerned with the realtime loaded size than the realtime content.

Comment: If I knew a way to do this in VBScript I would have suggested it.